# Programmatically detecting completed failed Spark jobs using Spark Launcher

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-launcher

I am using the `org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher` class to launch and monitor Spark jobs on my Yarn cluster. Unfortunately, it is not detecting jobs that exit prematurely due to an uncaught exception.

Looking at the jobs in the Yarn Resource Manager Web UI, they have a `State` of `FINISHED` and a `FinalStatus` of `FAILED`. When I call `SparkAppHandle.getState()` for the job, it returns `FINISHED` and not `FAILED`.

I am using spark-launcher 2.10 and Spark 1.6